# Definition of closed and open sets in normed vector spaces

Tags: real-analysis

I have the following problem:

Prove that:

(1).

$A = \{x \in l_2 : |x_n|\leq \frac{1}{n}, n = 1, 2, ...\}$ is a closed set in $l_2$, where $l_2$ is a vector space.

(2).

$B=\{ x \in l_2 : |x_n| < \frac{1}{n}, n = 1, 2, ...\}$ is not an open set.

Solution for part (1):

We know that $(x_j)_{j=1}^{\infty} \in l_2$, then $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}(x_j)^2 < \infty$. Moreover, we know that foreach $(x_j)_{j=1}^{\infty} \in A, then \  |x_j| \le \frac{1}{j}$. So, the sequence $\frac{1}{j}, \  j=1, 2,...$ is a limit of all sequences in A, because each one of them converges to an element in $\frac{1}{j}$ *(Not sure if corect?)*. Then the set A will be closed $iff$ $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{j^2} < \infty$, which is true, so $(\frac{1}{j})_{j=1}^{\infty}$ is in $l_2$ and A is closed in this vector space.

I have solved the first part in the abovementioned way, but I am not sure if my assumption about $\frac{1}{j}$ is clear and can help me prove the statement.

The second part of the problem should be closely related to the first one. I have a hint for it. It says: Does $B_\epsilon(0)\subset B$.

Comment: To show that $A$ is closed, show that for each $k$, the set $A_k=\{x\in l_2: |x_k|\leq\frac{1}{k}\}$ is closed. What do you know about intersections of closed sets?

Comment: Yes, for part one I can use that the intersection between closed sets will be closed and for part two, that an infinite intersection between open sets need not to be open.